# Angular grunt build can't find uglifyjs module during distribution build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, npm

When running the test build, everything works find but when I try to build the distribution, I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module '/Users/matt.sich/Documents/angularProjects/firstProject/node_modules/grunt-usemin/lib/config/uglifyjs' Use --force to continue.
```

I checked that folder and the module is there. I have it installed in npm. 
I tried removing the npm modules directory and reinstalling with npm install. This didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Let me ask you this... did you upgrade to WIndows 10?  There is a reason I ask that involves node and your Environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the package.json and having ^s in front of the versions. The ^ updates to new minor versions of the dependencies. It's better practice to not use ^s and instead use the actual version you want to use and manually update the versions when needed. 
Here's a way to migrate from ^s to version numbers: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates